Why Wireshark doesn't capture outgoing api requests made by localhost app backend?
I'm trying to use Wireshark to capture outging network traffic made by a localhost app's backend. Specifically, this "network traffic" is an api request made by the localhost app's backend to a remote api endpoint.

[Please note that other seemingly similar questions, either:

Refer to capturing traffic between frontent client (browser, usually) and backend, which is not what I discuss here (namely, api call by the backend).
Refer to seeing the actual packet content eventhough it's https (e.g. this one) - again, not of interest here; I just wanna see the call being made (I'll take it from there, hopefully).
Has no answer, maybe because they are not detailed enough (e.g. this one).]



Question: For some reason, I don't see the api request being captured - Why is that, and how can I see it?
Details:
I'm going to be as detailed as I can be to explain what I did:

The localhost app is running on Windows Server 2019, and it's a .NET 6 app.
The localhost app runs on http://localhost:5000/.
The localhost app backend makes the api call while I'm debugging the app.
The remote api being called is an https api.
The remote api returns status code 401.

In Wireshark, I tried two different setups:
First setup:
I listen to both Ethernet and the loopback (I was unsure which should I pick), using a filter for port 5000, and then hit the start button (first image below). I then start the localhost app (these are the 18 packets in image 2) and make the api call which then gets a 401 status (image 3) - but nothing is captured after the first  lines which are just the app being started:
Image 1 - Wireshark setup

Image 2 - Starting the app while Wireshark is capturing

Image 3 - Debugging the app while Wireshark is capturing

Second setup:
Again, I listen to both Ethernet and the loopback, but without the filter for port 5000.
After hitting the start button, I added a filter to show only traffic whose ip.src == 127.0.01. I expected to see some outgoing traffic where the destination ip would be something other than the localhost ip, but as can be seen in the screenshot, there's no such outgoing traffic:

Code I'm using:
Install Nuget package Azure.AI.OpenAI 2.0.0-beta.2 (prerelease), and then use this code:
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var url = args[1];
    var api_key = args[2]; 

    var openAIClient = new OpenAIClient(
        credential: new System.ClientModel.ApiKeyCredential(api_key),
        options: new OpenAIClientOptions() { Endpoint = new Uri(url) }
    );
    var chatClient = openAIClient.GetChatClient("gpt-4o");
    var response = chatClient.CompleteChat(new ChatMessage[] {
        new SystemChatMessage("You are a helpful assistant that talks like a pirate."),
        new UserChatMessage("Hi, can you help me?"),
    });
}


Next, I think that OpenAI does not run on your machine. Therefore it must connect into the Internet and it can't do that from 127.0.0.1 but it needs your real IP address, e.g. 192.168.xx.xx, which means that your filter is wrong. Try tcp.port == 5000 as the display filter instead.

@ThomasWeller, sure, code added. I also tried your display filter suggestion for tcp.port == 5000, but the result is the same: the only values in the Source and Destination columns are 127.0.0.1.

Localhost (127.0.0.1) and the 5000 port are both irrelevant for this, I believe, since those relate to the connection between your client and your host service. What you want to filter on is the IP of the endpoint that your service is calling out to. If you don't have the IP you can get that from pinging the host name. You must have the port number in your configuration, but you can probably just spy on all traffic to that IP.

@500-InternalServerError, yes, I see it now! here it is - so a followup: which packet is most likely the actual request (with headers and body)?

That's probably the Application Data ones, but the content is encrypted (SSL) as you already know.
